# Finding record by multiple fieldNames in ExtJs store

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-stores

If I need to find a record in EXTJS store, I typically use [findRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findRecord) method. It takes the name of the field and the value you want to search.

```
myStore.findRecord('EmployeeID', rec.empId);
```

But what If I want to search store for a record based on multiple fields. Lets say I want to search record by `Employee ID` and `Employee Departamet ID`

I am using ExtJs 4.1

Answer (score 2):

Use findBy and pass a custom function

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/?mobile=/api/Ext.data.Store#method-findBy

Comment: Link should be https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/?mobile=/api/Ext.data.Store#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-findBy